# Run xgboost on Google Cloud Dataproc

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, distributed-computing, xgboost, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm a newbie to distributed learning on virtual machines. Now I have a large dataset and want to run xgboost on Google Cloud Dataproc. I checked the tutorial in xgboost git about running on AWS, but I think this is different from Google Cloud.

Any advice, relevant links, tutorials would be much appreciated!

Sincerely!

Answer (score 2):

I would say that [`Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine`](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=emea-es-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-gcp-1003963&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_253509872113-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20~%20EXA_M%3A1_ES_EN_ML_MLE_Cloud%20Machine-KWID_43700018961394479-kwd-287808589816-userloc_20287&utm_term=KW_google%20machine%20learning%20cloud-ST_google%20machine%20learning%20cloud&ds_rl=1245734&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjvq_lb7S2gIVRecbCh2ukgdQEAAYASAAEgJdw_D_BwE&dclid=CNPOwpa-0toCFVcw0wodC5QCKQ) (`Cloud ML`) is the most appropriate product for Machine Learning algorithms because it is a managed service and you can focus on model development without worrying about infrastructure. [Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/xgboost/notebooks/Online%20Prediction%20with%20XGBoost.ipynb) is a tutorial about online Prediction with XGBoost on `Cloud ML`.

As you mentioned that you have a large dataset, maybe it is interesting to have a look into [this document](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/11/using-apache-spark-with-tensorflow-on-google-cloud-platform) that explains how to combine the use of `Google Cloud Dataproc` to preprocess the data and `Cloud ML` for prediction.